# How to redirect website visitors to a random url

Tags: javascript, html

How can I redirect a visitor that accesses example.com/page1 to a random link selected out of 5 links?

I‘ve seen several code scripts here but they all require the visitor to click on a button to be redirected. I want the user to be redirected as soon as he accesses my website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.href` on  window.onload. As soon as the window loads it will redirect to the said link

```js
window.onload=function(){
window.location.href = "http://abcss.net";
}
```